# Can't implement protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` that contains a button, when the user taps the button or select a cell I need to present an action sheet with two buttons. Both button fires a segue and I'm passing data (from the cell) inside the `prepareForSegue:` method. It's working fine, but I would like to do it with a protocol but unfortunately I couldn't implement it properly.

This is how I do it now:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFUser *userObj;

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ContactsTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    PFUser *user = [self.dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.usernm.text = user.username;
    cell.userId.text = user.objectId;

    cell.cellButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.cellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return cell;
}

- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender {

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    self.userObj = [self.dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:button.tag];
   [self setupActionSheet];

}

- (void) setupActionSheet {


    AHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [[AHKActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(nil, nil)];

    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Button 1", nil)
                              image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1"]
                               type:AHKActionSheetButtonTypeDefault
                            handler:^(AHKActionSheet *as) {

                                [Utilz checkUser:self.userObj.objectId with:self.userObj.username];

                            }];

    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Button 2", nil)
                              image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2"]
                               type:AHKActionSheetButtonTypeDefault
                            handler:^(AHKActionSheet *as) {


                                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"presentNextView" sender:self];

                            }];

    [actionSheet show];


}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"presentNextView"]) {
        if ([[segue destinationViewController] isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerTwo class]]) {

            ViewControllerTwo *dataToPass = [segue destinationViewController];

            dataToPass.usrStr = self.usrObj.username;
            dataToPass.objStr = self.usrObj.objectId;

        }
    }
}
```

And here is my attempt to do it with a protocol:

First, I created a protocol called `DataPassProtocol.h`.

Then I added an ENUM to the `ContactsTableViewCell.h` and imported `DataPassProtocol.h`

`typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyUserCellAction) {
       MyUserCellActionCheckUser,
       MyUserCellActionPerformSegue
   };`

I also added these variables into the `ContactsTableViewCell.h`

```
@property (weak) id <DataPassProtocol> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFUser *user; 
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender;
```

In the `ContactsTableViewCell.m` I added these methods

```
 - (void)setUser:(PFUser *)user {
        _user = user;
        // setup UI
        self.usernmLabel.text = _user.username;
        self.userIdLabel.text = _user.objectId;

    }
    - (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
        // cell handles its button being tapped 
        NSLog(@"Button tapped");

        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myUser:didPerformAction:)]) {
            [self.delegate myUser:self.user didPerformAction:MyUserCellActionCheckUser];
        }
       if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myUser:didPerformAction:)]) {
            [self.delegate myUser:self.user didPerformAction:MyUserCellActionPerformSegue];
        } 
    }
```

Here I got an error at the second if statement.

> Implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') to 'id' is disallowed
>   with ARC

I don't really know why this happens.

Another error:

```
an Expected a type in this method implementation of the protocol file.

- (void)myUser:(PFUser *)user didPerformAction:(MyUserCellAction)action;
```

Furthermore in `MyDelegateViewController` I'm getting this warning:

> Conflicting parameter types in implementation of
>   'myUser:didPerformAction:': '__strong id' vs 'MyUserCellAction' (aka
>   'enum MyUserCellAction')

And I placed this in my VC where my table view is.

```
- (void)myUser:(PFUser *)user didPerformAction:(MyUserCellAction)action {
    if (action == MyUserCellActionCheckUser) {
        // do what we want

    } else if (action == MyUserCellActionPerformSegue) {
        // do the other thing we want
    }
}
```

and here is the protocol implementation:

```
@protocol DataPassProtocol <NSObject>


@optional

- (void)myUser:(PFUser *)user didPerformAction:(MyUserCellAction)action;
```

How could I make it work? It's my first protocol, so I don't really know how should I do it right.

Comment: Could you post the protocol? It seems you have some problem with the protocol declaration

Comment: You could try declaring the enum in the `DataProtocol.h` file, because that's where it should be declared, cause it is connected to the protocol, not the cell.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, from what you've described, that you haven't imported a definition of your MyUserCellAction enum into your protocol. If you want to use an enum, I would move the definition of the MyUserCellAction enum into the protocol (your cell is importing the protocol anyway, so will have access to this definition). I would also call the protocol something a bit more descriptive, like CellActioning or ContactsTableViewCellDelegate.

On the other hand, I would recommend not passing the enum at all, but instead having two methods `performSegueActionForUser:(PFUser *)user` `performCheckActionForUser:(PFUser *)user` or something along those lines.

Passing an enum or boolean flag into a method call to decide what action the method should perform is an example of Control Coupling, which is discouraged if following proper software engineering principles.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29

Comment: upvote for the mention of control coupling and the link to why that is discouraged!